# react-native-fbsdk onLoginFinished fails to execute on android device

Tags: android, react-native, apk, react-native-fbsdk

Library: `"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0"`.
Use case: `Android User logs in via Facebook OAuth webview`.
Expected: `Upon successful authentication, app redirects to the user landing page.`
Actual: `Upon inputting credentials, app hangs at the Facebook "login success" notification screen.`

Note: this behavior ONLY occurs on an android device. Running the same apk on the emulator - via drag n drop - successfully redirects to the landing page. Doing a `git diff`, I find that code has not changed since I initially added it to the app. I am unable to duplicate this behavior on any AVD, so I doubt it's device-specific. When I first successfully implemented the SDK, the login worked flawlessly.

Unfortunately, I don't have an android device with which to test it myself.

Troubleshooting steps:

1. Rebuilt apk from previous git commits
2. Manually deliver apk to beta testers via cloud account vs. beta installer service
3. Confirmed key hash on FB dev portal.
4. Tried to step through the RN code using the debugger, but it fails to stop at any breakpoints placed on the FB-related code like `onLoginFinished()`

At this point, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Try to logout or expire the token manually first.

Comment: I think I found what happened. Had the user log out of FB. When they tried to log into my app, they received an "invalid key hash" error.